# Android Google Place Api next page

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am calling GooglePlaceAPI with HttpConnection.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longtitude+"&types=" + params[0] + "&radius=" + params[1] + "&key=" + GOOGLE_KEY
```

If result is more than more than 20, I am getting 20+ result. I can't get 1-20 result. But I want to get all results. I hear about next_page_token but I dont know how to use.

How can i my page token or next_page_token ? and How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: See the example in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging

Answer (score 1):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longtitude+"&types=" + params[0] + "&radius=" + params[1] + "&key=" + GOOGLE_KEY
```

parse  `next_page_token` from above api json response

then call api once more with `pagetoken='next_page_token'` as given below

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longtitude+"&pagetoken='next_page_token'&types=" + params[0] + "&radius=" + params[1] + "&key=" + GOOGLE_KEY
```

this will give you next 20 results.. continue parsing next_page_token from api call and then again call  api with next_page_token to get the further results